# How to download all IPA files that already deleted from AppStore?

Tags: games, in-app-purchase, 32-bit, ios

I am still wondering if there's a big archive of all and old IPA files that was on AppStore long years ago.
Because most of 32bit games is deleted from AppStore after iOS 10-11 release.

I saved some of them from my purchases sections, but not all of them is available for download from there. I don't understand why.

Isn't it possible to "catch" Apple server link, where it stores all IPA versions of games for certain iOS versions? It would be great, because current ways to install older version of apps (or deleted apps even) are so difficult.

That's sad, because there are ton of various iOS games that lost forever due to Apple strict applications rules etc, due to 64bit games later.

I don't have many apps in my purchases list, and of course I can extract them, but I can't decrypt them, I don't understand how to do it, to share it with anyone. Thanks!

P.S.
Some games included inapp purchases. Because of games being so, so old, now server doesn't work at all, and you can't buy anything, because server not responding, and Apple server too.
I don't know also, how to bypass it to unlock content.